# Query 1 table twice for 2 different count results

Tags: mysql

I'm very attracted to the idea of complex mysql statements however I am struggling with the documentation.

I have a soccer match table which is basically this:

```
match_id | home_team_id | away_team_id | home_score | away_score
----------------------------------------------------------------
    1    | 2            | 3            | 1          | 0        
    2    | 5            | 2            | 0          | 2
```

I need to do a few queries to do what I want

1. the total games played for a team
2. the total wins at home for a team
3. the total wins away for a team

I would do this via several arduous queries and then process them afterwards:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(match_id), SUM(home_score)
FROM 
    matches 
WHERE 
    home_team_id=2 
AND 
    home_score > away_score
```

And:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(match_id), SUM(away_score) 
FROM 
    matches 
WHERE 
    away_team_id=2 
AND 
    away_score > home_score
```

That seems like a lot of little repitition. I thought I might be able to do a union like this:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(match_id) as home_wins
FROM 
    matches
WHERE 
    home_team_id=2
AND 
    home_score > away_score
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    COUNT(match_id) as away_wins
FROM 
    matches
WHERE 
    away_team_id=2
AND 
    away_score > home_score
```

Which works somewhat but I think it is merging the results. How can it be done with one query?